# Onsubmit populates an array and then displays what's in the array

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to create a form that will store which boxes have been checked into an array.  (1-1, 1-2, 1-3, etc).  Then a new page would show or hide in depth steps based on which things were checked.  So I am trying to do something more simple right now by just populating an array onsubmit and then printing the values of what is in the array.  So far I have been unsuccessful.  I have posted the Javascript I am working on and the form call.  I also have a link: http://jsfiddle.net/kNsW9/13/

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return checked_boxes(this.id);" >
<script>
var checked =[];

function checked_boxes(form)
{   
    var getInputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var inputCount = getInputs.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
        if (getInputs[i].type === "checkbox" && getInputs[i].checked) {
            checked.push(getInputs[i].value);
        }/*
        else if (getInputs[i].type === "checkbox" && getInputs[i].unchecked) {
            checked.pop(getInputs[i].value);
        }*/
    }
}

function print_checked()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++)
    {
        document.write(checked[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If checked_boxes does not return false the form will be submitted and your page will reload, same for when an error occcurs (this is true in your case because string has no getElementsByTagName method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the id of the form to checked_boxes function; not the form itself.

Later in the checked_boxes function you assume the value passed is the form and not the forms id (wich is a string). String doesn't have a getElementsByTagName function.

To solve this you can change

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return checked_boxes(this.id);" >
```

to

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return checked_boxes(this);" >
```

Comment: that makes sense, I went ahead and fixed it but it still doesn't display the results

Comment: Because the form is submitted. The last line of checked_boxes should be: return false;

Comment: Better even would be to not have your function called onsubmit because you never intent to submit the form. But as I've mentioned before; when there is an error in your script the form will submit. This makes it harder to debug your script and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Now if I want to action="page2.php" in the form, it won't go to the new page.  Is it possible to submit it to the new page and that new page use it's information?

Comment: What would you suggest instead of using onsubmit

Comment: Yes, that's the PHP part. Your PHP file should show it based on what's POSTed

Comment: How do I make sure the checked_boxes function runs if I don't call it onSubmit?

Comment: Running onsubmit is ok. Completely understandable as long as you return false

Comment: What if I wanted it to go to a 2nd page and use the array though?  It appears that putting return false will prevent the action from occurring.